# QNAP container station API

Tags: api, qnap

I am trying to use the QNAP container station API, but I am not even able to authenticate. As it says in the documentation, I do the following:

```
curl -sq -XPOST -c cookies.txt -d "username=username&password=pwd" http://mynashostname.myqnapcloud.com:8080/api/v1/login
```

But instead of getting a JSON response, I am getting an HTML response telling me the page is not found. Am I even using the right port?

QNAP doc: http://qnap-dev.github.io/container-station-api/system.html

Answer (score 3):

The latest version of QNAP Container Station is v1.7.2502.

You have to upgrade it to the latest version and confirm that ${QPORT} is the same as the system port of NAS. (mentioned in QNAP doc)

Steps to check the system port: “Control Panel” > “General Settings”

QNAP doc: http://qnap-dev.github.io/container-station-api/system.html#post--api-v1-login